# Which ODBC connection properties have higher priority ?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, odbc

I take data from PostgreSQL via ODBC and put the data in excel worksheet. For this I use VBA which makes a query table. In the VBA script I specify a connection string which contains some ODBC settings

```
ConnectionString = "ODBC;DSN=PostgreSQL30;DATABASE=xxxxx;SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;PORT=5432;UID=xxx;;SSLmode=disable;ReadOnly=0;Protocol=7.4;FakeOidIndex=0;ShowOidColumn=0;RowVersioning=0;ShowSystemTables=0;ConnSettings=;Fetch=100;Socket=4096;UnknownSizes=0;MaxVarcharSize=255;MaxLongVarcharSize=8190;Debug=0;CommLog=0;Optimizer=0;Ksqo=0;UseDeclareFetch=1;TextAsLongVarchar=1;UnknownsAsLongVarchar=0;BoolsAsChar=1;Parse=1;CancelAsFreeStmt=0;ExtraSysTablePrefixes=dd_;;LFConversion=1;UpdatableCursors=1;DisallowPremature=0;TrueIsMinus1=0;BI=0;ByteaAsLongVarBinary=0;UseServerSidePrepare=1;LowerCaseIdentifier=0;GssAuthUseGSS=0;XaOpt=1"
```

For this ODBC connection there are settings in Windows 7 which are in ODBC Data Source Administrator > User DNS > PostgreSQL30 > Configure... > Datasource. This is the window

[image]

Which ODBC connection properties have higher priority - defined in windows setting or defined with a connection string?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, attributes set in an ODBC connect string will override attributes set in a DSN.